# What are some responses to Popper's "The Open Society and Its Enemies"?

Tags: reference-request, popper, marx

Can you recommend a good reference to answer the critiques in Popper's  "[The Open Society and Its Enemies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Open_Society_and_Its_Enemies)"? I am especially interested in responses to the Marx section of the book.

Comment: Maurice Cornforth -The Open Philosophy and the Open Society
http://www.amazon.co.uk/The-Open-Philosophy-Society/dp/0853151350

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Walter Kaufmann](http://www.hegel.net/en/kaufmann1959.htm) had some strong opinions on Popper's scholarship in "The Open Society and Its Enemies" More about Hegel than Marx, but probably worth reading anyway given Hegel's influence on Marx